# How to print value in UILabel from the values of TableView dynamically

Tags: swift, uitableview, checkbox

[image]

I'm having a tableView with a custom cell, whenever I click the checkbox button the value inside the cell increases i.e.,(0 to 1) in cell, and on uncheck value decreases, that works perfectly. But whenever I try to print those values from the cell to a UILabel outside tableView, the values are not changing.

This is the below code I have Used

```
   var data = [[String: AnyObject]]()

   func getDetails() {

    let paymentURL = paymentListURL + String(28) + "&student_id=" + String(33)

    Alamofire.request(paymentURL).responseJSON { (response) in
        if ((response.result.value) != nil) {
            var jsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
           print(jsonVar)

            if let da = jsonVar["types"].arrayObject {
                self.data = da as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }
            if self.data.count > 0 {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TabCell

    cell.checkB.tag = indexPath.row
    let ip = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameText.text = ip["title"] as? String
    if cell.nameText.text == "Mandatory testing" {

        cell.checkB.checkState = .checked
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.checkB.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    if ip["mandatory"] as? String == "yes" {
        moneyText.text = ip["amount"] as? String
       //moneyText is UILabel outside Tableview
        cell.amountValue.text = ip["amount"] as? String

        cell.checkB.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        moneyText.text = "0"
        if cell.amountValue.text == "1"{
            print("ONE")
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func didPressButton(_ tag: Int) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TabCell

    moneyText.text = String(cell.someValue)        
}
```

And for TableviewCell I Used

```
protocol TabCellDelegate {
   func didPressButton(_ tag: Int)
   }

class TabCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var checkB: M13Checkbox!

@IBOutlet weak var nameText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var amountValue: UILabel!

var someValue: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        amountValue.text = "\(someValue)"
    }
}

@IBAction func checkBAction(_ sender: M13Checkbox) {
    cellDelegate?.didPressButton(sender.tag)

    if checkB.checkState == .checked {
        someValue += 1

    } else if checkB.checkState == .unchecked {
        someValue -= 1

    }       
}

}
```

I tried first adding those values from cell to an Array, and then adding all the values in array and printing in UILabel, but the values are not changing, it was only incrementing.i.e., even after unchecking the checkbox the value is increasing.

I tried even using protocol it did not work for me

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating `someValue` from the `checkBAction` handler inside the `TabCell`. The property `didSet` handler will then update the `amountValue` label. This is the reason, why the cell's label is being updated.

You do not have any code that updates the `moneyText` after `someValue` changed. You only set `moneyText.text` from `tableView(_:cellForRow:)`, but this is called when a cell is being displayed, maybe multiple times after scrolling etc.

You could do the following:

- Create a *delegate* property inside the cell (use a custom protocol as type)
- Set the controller to be that delegate
- When the value changes, call a function of that delegate (e.g. call the controller)
- Inside that, update the `moneyText`

---

As an idea (might not compile because I don't have all your classes):

```
protocol MyTabCellProtocol {
    func checkboxChanged(_ checkbox:M13Checkbox, atRow:Integer) 
}

class TabCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak delegate:MyTabCellProtocol?

    // ...
    @IBAction 
    func checkBAction(_ sender: M13Checkbox) {

        if checkB.checkState == .checked {
            someValue += 1

        } else if checkB.checkState == .unchecked {
            someValue -= 1
        }
        delegate?.checkboxChanged(self, checkB.tag)
    }
}

class MyController : UIViewController, MyTabCellProtocol {
    func checkboxChanged(_ checkbox:M13Checkbox, atRow:Integer) {
        moneyText.text = "\(checkbox.someValue)"
    }
}
```

---

But if I think further, I would suggest to refactor the whole code a little. The problem I see is that your action handler inside the cell does update the `someValue` property of the cell, but does not update the outside model (`ip["amount"]`). I think what you should do is:

- Inside the cell's `checkBAction`, just call the delegate and provide the information about the row that has been modified (`self.checkB.tag`) and the check state. Do *not* update the `amountValue` here!
- In the delegate implementation, update the model `ip["amount"]`
- Call `reloadRows(at:with:)` of the table view to refresh the cell
- Then, `cellForRow` is automatically being called, in which you then update the cell and the outer label.

Comment: I used delegate method but cell behaves differently, when clicking and unclicking, the values are not synching. e.g., if we click multiple checkboxes at a time.

Comment: See my updated answer: You really should update the model (`ip["amount"]`) and refresh the cell. Only this will keep model and view in sync.

Comment: ip["amount"] is nothing, I get it from the API., The thing is I am getting correct values inside the label in a cell, but I am not able to fetch those changing values inside the cell to print outside to a Label

Comment: I put some code inside my answer, but you should really think of updating the model, and the updating the view.

Comment: I tried similar to this, but label value behaves strangely

Comment: To debug, you could do the following: 1.) Create a func that modifies the label text; 2.) Always call this func to modify the label, do not modify it directly; 3.) Add a breakpoint here and check why it is called with which parameters

Comment: Is there any solution like a counter, increase and decrease  a value

Comment: Yes, you could do so in your delegate method.

Comment: That's true,  my question is can I just copy the values inside the tableview cell(1 or 0)  append them to an array and then add those array values and print on the UILabel

Comment: You should not access any global array from within the cell. You should call a delegate (e.g. the _controller_) which will do the work for you. Work with the _model_, not with the content of the cells.

Comment: I'm getting stuck at the moment, is it good to use Firebase for this, e.g., adding and decreasing value to firebase. and print it to label